# Question about a Hop Chart

Tags: hops, bitterness

I've seen [this chart](http://www.hopschart.com/zoom.html) several times in bars and such, and was looking at little closer at the numbers. The bottom graph i can agree with on the numbers, but the top part listing the different characteristics I can't.

For starters having a scale of % seems wrong. I could perhaps start agreeing with with things if it was changed to mL/100 gram sample of total oil, or I at least could start back calculating into something that gives me a rough number to match those on the scale.

So, anyone know how the chart numbers were determined? Yes I sent an email to who is suppose to the author of the chart, still awaiting an answer,

Comment: You're asking how numbers were derived on a chart who's author is seemingly not a member of this site. This question is not answerable, in my opinion.

Comment: Probably not, was hoping there was someone here that had done some research into such an area and could weigh in on the subject

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate answer, perhaps, but I recommend you not believe any hop analysis that you don't receive from a lab, personally. The worst case should be that you use direct laboratory information obtained by someone that you've chosen to trust. Anything else, don't rely on it.

The internet is full of so much BS when it comes to hops, that most of what you read is crap. It's sad, but it's true.

Just trying to help you out. Brew single hop beers with a neutral grain and yeast, trust your senses, and build your own database.

Comment: I have lab data and was comparing it to the chart. The bottom chart was pretty accurate, low end was off on one scale and I'm guessing the creator did that to keep it pretty. The top one was where my questions were at (oil breakdown). Again goign by the lab data I have available the numbers are way off if going by %, not even close. However if the creator used the wrong units I could see how things would work out. Even with the units being wrong the ratio between oils seems correct

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're asking about the listings for the amount of a particular type of oil in the hops.  That is derived empirically by measuring the hops.

Comment: Yes I know that, and I have listing for various hops types and the percentage % of the different types of oil out of the total oil. The numbers I have from a Hop Union booklet don't match the percentages given in the above chart. I think the author meant to use a scale of ml/100 Grams  and not % for the types of oils, and just trying to confirm this. Since the author hasn't gotten back to me I was curious if anyone here had tried to verify the chart since it has been around for a couple of years and if they had how they made the part of the chart for Myercene, etc. work.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand your question.